# Enumerate directory for a collection of metadata objects, not names

Tags: c#, .net, winapi

.NET's `Directory.EnumerateXXX` methods return a collection of strings. Meanwhile, the underlying Win32 API (`FindFirstFile` and related) return the full set of file/folder metadata - attributes, datetimes, size. Short of P/Invoke, is there a method in .NET that would return the collection of the metadata carrying objects (e. g. `FileInfo's) in one call?

"No" is an acceptable answer.

**I am aware of `Enumerate` followed by constructing `FileInfo` around the path.** The question is - can one do it without O(N) I/O calls.

Comment: DirectoryInfo.EnumerateFileSystemInfos (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directoryinfo.enumeratefilesysteminfos) ?

Comment: Make an answer, I'll accept.

Comment: Kinda obvious, a simple look at the docs would have shown you that function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would be the [DirectoryInfo.EnumerateFileSystemInfos Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directoryinfo.enumeratefilesysteminfos) which

> Returns an enumerable collection of file system information (`System.IO.FileSystemInfo`) in the
> current directory.